# MVC Razor - Error with ActionLink within a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC - Razor - I'm pretty new to it and I'm having a bit of trouble generating an ActionLink within a grid ...

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
            //Some grid setting stuff here
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(null, null,
                    @<div class="vehicleResult">

                            @{ 
                                var text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Shell Shape"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Model"));
                                @Html.ActionLink(text, MVC.Search.ActionNames.VehicleView, MVC.Search.Name, new { Id = item.Id }, new { });
                            }

                        <a>@string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Shell Shape"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Model"))</a>
              )))
```

The < a > tag at the end works fine, but I want the text from the < a > tag i.e.

```
@string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Manufacturer"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Shell Shape"), item.Value.GetPropertyValue("Model"))
```

sent through to an ActionLink (the bit above).

Also if I do ...

```
 var text = "blah";
 @Html.ActionLink(text, MVC.Search.ActionNames.VehicleView, MVC.Search.Name, new { Id = item.Id }, new { });
```

then that's fine - it's just when they're together it doesn't work ... the error I get is ...

```
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<GIT.RetailWebsite.App.ViewModels.VehicleSearchModel> 
has no applicable method named 'ActionLink' but appears to have an extension 
method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. 
Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method 
without the extension method syntax.    
d:\TFSProjects\Retail Website\Main\src\Retail Website\GIT.RetailWebsite.App\Views\Search\_grsResultsGrid.cshtml 31  GIT.RetailWebsite.App
```

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you try to use the `dynamic` `text` variable in an extension method (`ActionLink`) and dynamic arguments not supported when calling extension methods.
The `text`variable is `dynamic` because it's constructed from the `dynamic` `item` argument.

Although the exception message a little bit cryptic it describes what you can do:

Cast the dymanic argument:

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)text, 
     MVC.Search.ActionNames.VehicleView, 
     MVC.Search.Name, new { Id = item.Id }, new { });
```

Or call the extension method as a static method:

```
@LinkExtensions.ActionLink(Html, text, 
     MVC.Search.ActionNames.VehicleView, 
     MVC.Search.Name, new { Id = item.Id }, new { });
```